# How to compute manually log-likelihood from model deviance with GLM?

Tags: r, glm

I am doing this exercise of a partial on GLM with R.
Please consider this GLM () R output:

[image]

1. With only this output, how to get the model' log-likelihood?
   With R it's easy:

   logLik(model)

And it's the same value as deviance/-2

But I'm not sure with this last formula (deviance/-2).
Never in my course, it's written this formula.

In my course, to test global model significativity, 2 hypothesis:
H0 : Model 1 = Beta0
H1 : Model 2 = Beta0 + Beta1 . X1

And Likelihood  test rate = deviance(Model1) - deviance(Model2)

```
= -2 ln(likelihood Model1 / likelihood Model2)
```

follows a Khi2 law with a number of df = (model2 df - model1 df)
Can you explain me please?
Thanks you!

Comment: See [this Cross Validated post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229824/why-is-a-glms-residual-deviance-minus-twice-its-log-likelihood).